# Service must return a value $get factory method

Tags: angularjs

citiesService.js

```
 var fn = function ($http, $log, $q) {

    var data = {list:list};

    function list(couponCode) {
        return $http.get('/Customer/Cities/Index',
            {
                params: { couponCode: couponCode },
                cache: true
            });

    }
    return data;
}
```

Here I am trying to get data from `Index` method that returns a list of cities but I am getting an error in console

> [$injector:undef] Provider 'citiesService' must return a value from $get factory method.

Comment: How do you register this service with Angular?

Comment: angular.module('app')
    .factory('citiesService', ['$http', '$log', '$q', fn]);
})

Comment: We need more code, is your `fn` defined belown or above the `angular.module` line? My guess is that `fn` is undefined while registering the service

Comment: No @Deblaton camel casing is allowed 'citiesService' is ok

Comment: How do you call the `list` function?

Comment: The code you posted alone, can't produce this error. Post complete usage example, otherwise it's not reproducible.

Comment: Please use jsfiddle, jsbin... to replicate your scenario

Comment: I am calling it by cities controller ex. 

  citiesService.list(couponCode).then(function (data) {
         
            }
        });
        
    }

Comment: @Dieterg The the error would be different.

Comment: fiddle :  https://jsfiddle.net/5jpaayy9/4/

Comment: Are you using any style guide for defining factory?. It's somewhat different than what we use

Comment: Provide a working fiddle, whatever you've shared is the code that is there in question and comments. If you are not allowed to share your code try to replicate the behavior with a working copy so that users can debug the code

Comment: Alright ,I will do that